# Return values from proactive dialog

Tags: botframework

My scenario is something like this, there are 2 users -> U1 and U2.

U1 wants the bot to ping U2 and get some information back

This is where i use proactive dialog based messages.

I am currently using the v3 Bot Builder SDK [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-a-dialog-based-proactive-message)

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.Container, message))
{
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //This is our dialog stack
    var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

    // Interrupt the stack. This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
    // Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation

    var dialog = new GetFeedbackDialog(this.UserData);

    task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);

    await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    // Flush the dialog stack back to its state store.
    await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);

}

class GetFeedbackDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private RequestFeedbackData userData;

    public GetFeedbackDialog()
    {
    }

    public GetFeedbackDialog(RequestFeedbackData userData)
    {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Hello, Please provide feedback for "+ userData.OrganizerName+" on "+userData.FeedbackSubject);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        if (message.Text.ToLower().Equals("quit"))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Quitting.. Thank you for using FeedbackBot!");
            context.Done(String.Empty); // Finish this dialog.
        }

        await context.PostAsync("Thank you for your feedback!");
        context.Done(message.Text);
    }
}
```

How do can i access the response typed by U2 in GetFeedbackDialog from where i initiated the proactive message ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you using any specific channels?

I think the approach would be to use your state storage to get the reference to that response. You are successful in getting the proactive message to U2, correct?

Comment: I am using Teams as the messaging channel, yes i am able to send proactive message to U2.